# How to share stickers to whatsapp using a React Native expo-cli

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to implement an application that will let the user add stickers to whatsapp but I couldn't find anything about how to do it except react-native-whatsapp-stickers package but unfortunately I don't think it supports expo-cli. I am trying to think maybe I can do it with the Linking package (from react-native) or something but still I don't know where the stickers are saved! did anyone do something like that before using expo?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, did you finally found anything?

Comment: I found this package(https://github.com/Jobeso/react-native-whatsapp-stickers) but Unfortunately it only works with react-native-cli. I tried and it worked